# MongoDB won't save array of data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save an array of strings stored in another variable to my MongoDB database using Mongoose.

Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    user: String,
    guild: String,
    content: String,
    attachment: String,
    messages: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("messages", schema, "messages")
```

My code:

```js
const messageSchema = require("../models/messageSchema");

const messages = ["array", "of", "strings"];

// Save Data
const data = new messageSchema({
    _id: "1234567890",
    user: "1234567890",
    guild: "1234567890",
    content: "Hello World",
    attachment: null,
    messages: messages
})

await data.save();
```

It saves all data except for the messages array. For messages it just is an empty array.
I do not get any errors in console either.

I have tried using a `for` loop to push to a array from the `messages` array, which did not work either.

```js
const messages = ["array", "of", "strings"];

let data = new messageSchema({
    _id: "1234567890",
    user: "1234567890",
    guild: "1234567890",
    content: "Hello World",
    attachment: null,
    messages: []
})

for(const msg of messages) {
    data.messages.push(msg);
}
```

I have also trying different ways of defining the array in the schema like:

```js
messages: [String]
```

```js
messages: [{ type: String }]
```

Answer (score 0):

change your schema like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
 _id: String,
 user: String,
 guild: String,
 content: String,
 attachment: String,
 messages: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed   
},{ strict: false } )

module.exports = mongoose.model("messages", schema)
```

I hope this will fix your problem

Comment: The same problem is occurring while using this as the schema.

Comment: you can contact me directly for solving this issue.